# Coerce pointer to member to most derived type

Tags: c++, c++11, pointer-to-member

Consider this type hierarchy:

```
struct A {
    int x;
};

struct B : A {
    int y;
};
```

The type of `&B::y` is `int B::*`, but the type of `&B::x` is `int A::*`. It can be convertible to `int B::*`, which is what I need, but I need to explicitly perform that conversion.

Is there a handy way of deducing the type to be a pointer to a member of the class I specified? After all, if I wanted an `A::*` to `x` I could do `&A::x`.

Comment: A "handy way"? What's the context? Is a weird expression like `bikeshed<B>([](auto wrapper){ return &unwrap<decltype(wrapper)>::x; })` handy? Edit: oops, that's C++14

Comment: @dyp Just want to avoid having to write something like `template <typename Derived, typename CLS, typename T> T Derived::* to_derived(T CLS::*member)`, cause then `to_derived<B>(&B::x)` is a bit annoying to type when the name of `B` is long. Was just hoping there was some clever way I was missing.

Comment: You could try to deduce the parameter type of a non-polymorphic lambda's `operator()`, then `bikeshed([](tag<B> d){ return &unwrap<decltype(d)>::x })` is possible. If there's only a small set of member names like `x`, it certainly is possible to use `bikeshed<B>(x_name)` for some helper object `x_name`.

Comment: You may still shorten that with `#define member_ptr(C, m) to_derived<C>(&C::m)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah that's what I ended up with. Seems like a weird aspect of the type system no?

Answer (score 0):

Such conversion would not be possible in case of virtual inheritance. Assume

```
struct A {
  int x;
};

struct B : virtual A {
  int y;
};
```

and two functions,

```
int f(B* pB) {
  int A::*pX = &A::x; // or &B::x, identical but clearer this way
  return pB->*pX;
}

int g(B* pB) {
  int B::*pY = &B::y;
  return pB->*pY;
}
```

`f(B*)` needs to make a vtable lookup in order to find the base pointer of `A` instance within `*pB` while `g(B*)` only applies an offset to `pB`. Therefore the object `&A::x` can not be expressed as an instance of a type `int B::*`, it needs a different runtime logic to evaluate with a pointer to `B` than an `int B::*` would.

Even though `B` is the most derived class here and now, one might define another class `C` inheriting both `A` and `B` *in a different compilation unit* and want to pass a `C*` to `f()`. So the offset of `A` within `B` can not be taken for fixed.

One could argue that the language could permit the conversion if no virtual inheritance is present, or in anonymous namespaces, or... but it was probably easier to disallow it consistently.